# E/ddms IllegalArgumentException 'Bad version' with both 32 and 64 bit Java JRE installed

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

### E/ddms IllegalArgumentException 'Bad version' with both 32 and 64 bit Java JRE installed

Hello.  Working on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit system, that has the 64-bit Java JDK (and via the JDK the JRE) installed, and using Eclipse 3.5.2 and the latest Android SDK (rev 7).  Everything works fine.

If I then install the 32-bit Java JRE on the same machine (so that I can run Java applets in Chrome/Firefox), and try to start up the emulator (from either the command prompt or from within Eclipse), I get the following exception...

```
E/ddms: shutting down due to uncaught exception
E/ddms: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad version: standalone
     at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.normalizeVersion(SdkStatsService.java:467)
     at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.doPing(SdkStatsService.java:195)
     at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.ping(SdkStatsService.java:130)
     ...
```

What specifically happens, when I try and launch the emulator, is I get a Windows command prompt window with a title of "Java -version", which quickly goes away, then another Windows command prompt window with a title of "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", which also goes away quickly, and then finally a third Windows command prompt window with the above-mentioned exception information in it, and with a title of ...

"java   -Djava.ext.dirs=lib\x86;lib\ -Dcom.android.ddms.binddir= -jar lib\ddms.jar ping emulator standal..."
(the '...' is because the window was not wide enough to show the rest of the title)

... which also quickly goes away.  All three windows display/disappear within a 1-2 second span of time.

Uninstalling/removing the 32-bit Java JRE from my system makes the problem go away, reintroducing the Java 32-bit JRE causes it to come back.

For now I'm just not having the 32-bit Java JRE installed, and if I need to access a web page with a Java applet, I use the 64-bit version of I.E. (which Java 64-bit works in), but I'd like to be able to have harmony between my Android/Eclipse 64-bit development environment, and my need to run the 32-bit of the Java JRE so I can use applets in Chrome/Firefox.

Any advice/info would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

P.S. Here's a composite screenpic of the three Windows command prompt windows that I described earlier: http://img409.imageshack.us/img409/3182/tempb.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exactly problem. In my case, I am running Windows 7 32bits. I found solution:

Modify ddms.bat in C:\android-sdk-windows\tools folder. The last line from

call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir= -jar %jarpath% %*

to:

call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir= -jar %jarpath% ping emulator 0012

It works for me.

Reference: http://ichavo.ru/voprosy/10-11-15/illegalargumentexception-bad-version-standalone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I was able to solve it.  My situation is that I had two installed JREs, and one JDK.  The Android docs say that you need the full JDK, so I decided to uninstall the two JREs.  After I did that, things still weren't working (though with a different error), and then I found what might have been the root cause of my problem.

In short, when things weren't working, I had this situation.  My JAVA_HOME system property was pointing to the JDK, and my PATH system property was pointing to the bin folder of one of the JREs.

The error that I got after I uninstalled my JREs was that Eclipse (3.5.1, 32 bit) wouldn't start up at all, saying it couldn't find the Java executable (or something along those lines).  So I fixed up the PATH to point to the JDK's bin folder.  After making this change, everything works fine now, and I can test out my Android programs.

So I'm happy with the end result, but here is the weird part of all this.  My system is 64 bit, and runs Windows Vista.  I can't get the Eclipse 3.5.1 64 bit version to work at all - I'm running the 32 bit version.  I don't remember if my JDK is 32 or 64 bit, but probably 64 bit (as that seems like what I would have chosen at the time).

And here is the last mystery that I don't understand - I still get the same exception message on the third Windows command prompt window that pops up when I test my app (E/ddms: shutting down due to uncaught exception...)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To fix error i did following task:

**1.** Run the Android application (Right click  on the Project >>Run As >>> Android Application)it will start your emulator then  let the emulator run.

**2.** Then check whether PATH variable in the Environment Variables set it to Android SDK Tools directory.

**3.** Then go to command prompt give command 'ddms' to start the Dalvik Debug Monitor.

**4.** Then again  run the application as explained in the step 1.

Then see the emulator screen to see required result.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But I could not get it to work with either an installation of only 32-bit jre nor only 64-bit jre. I never had both versions installed at the same time. Luckily I found this: http://www.lightsoft.se/?p=527.

Enter these commands in a command prompt after starting an emulator (and leaving it running):

```
adb kill-server
adb logcat-c
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, its a great link, but I don't understand how this relates to my original question of 32/64 java jre/jdk incompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *VERY* crude method to fix it but worked for me.

I faced this same error.

It appeared from above comments that this happens due to some sort of conflict between various versions of JREs. I simply searched for java.exe on my entire machine and deleted all the directories that contained Java.

I know this is crude but works for me as I did not use any of those programs.

I guess removing all these directories from PATH variable could have worked as well

amol