# Android HelloWorld IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have seen this question answered but the answers do not apply to me. I am a beginner to Android and I am trying to run HelloWorld with the Eclipse Plug-in that I have downloaded Api's 7 (2.1) and 8 (2.2) and have created a virtual devices for each version. I am running eclipse in xp with  1.6.0_22-b04 (32bit) no 64 bit jre installed on the system. I get the following stack trace when the emulator is launched:

IllegalArgumentException: bad version: standalone
com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsServer.normalizeVersion(SdkStatsService.java:467)
com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsServer.doPing(SdkStatsService.java:130)
com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsServer.ping(SdkStatsService.java:85)
com.android.ddms.Main.main(Main.java:85)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks,
francisco

Comment: How are you launching the emulator? That doesn't look like it would be your package.

Comment: I have the same problem as Francisco. The solution suggested by Peter doesn't look to fix the problem.
In my case I'm using Windows 7 + JDK1.6.

Any other idea?

Comment: i guess nobody is going to help me on this one. i will try another machine later.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you created a run configuration in Eclipse for normal (console) application which calls `com.android.ddms.Main.main`.

You need to create a run configuration for Android: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#run

**Edited:**

Apparently this happens if you have 32-bit JDKs installed on Windows 7. Try uninstalling 32-bit JDK and use 64-bit JDK instead.

Comment: Inside of Eclipse I am running an Android Application. When i lauch the SDK Manager outside of eclipse and try to start any of the Virtual Devices from there I get the same stack trace.  I just finish re-installing the XP operating system from scratch so there is barely anything else on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post but it does not apply to me. It might help Jaime out. I am still having my problem.

Here is a link with more detail about the Windows 7 problem:

[E/ddms IllegalArgumentException 'Bad version' with both 32 and 64 bit Java JRE installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921242/e-ddms-illegalargumentexception-bad-version-with-both-32-and-64-bit-java-jre-in)

On a machine that supports 64 bit i believe you will need to have the 64 jre/jdk installed. It definitly only supports one version of the jre.