# Eclipse Classic can not find java? and not run Hello World as last week

Tags: java, android

I installed Eclipse Classic (Helios) and Android Sdk and the Adt plugins as derscribed by goodle at the Android Developers site. I could immediately run Hello World perfectly. But the next time I used my computer I could run Hello World anymore and get this error message:

```
E/ddms: shutting down due to uncought exception
E/ddms: Bad version: standalone
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BadVersion: standalone
    at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.normalizeVersion<...>
    at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.doPing<...>
    at com.android.sdkstats.SdkStatsService.ping<...>
    at com.android.ddms.Main.main<Main.java:78>
```

And the console says:

```
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] Performing org.example.hello.Hello activity launch
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AnnasPhone'
[2010-12-22 21:38:52 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AnnasPhone'
[2010-12-22 21:38:58 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-12-22 21:38:58 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-12-22 21:39:39 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-12-22 21:39:39 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-12-22 21:39:39 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-12-22 21:40:26 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2010-12-22 21:40:26 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity org.example.hello.Hello on device emulator-5554
[2010-12-22 21:40:29 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.example.hello/.Hello }
```

and nothing happens... What should I do? Does Eclipse Classic needs some kind of configuration??

Anna

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the JRE that your program will run on by going to Window > Properties > Java < Installed JRE's.  However, I don't think this will solve your problem as I think it's an issue with the Android SDK and not Eclipse.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921242/e-ddms-illegalargumentexception-bad-version-with-both-32-and-64-bit-java-jre-in) is a post describing the same problem and the solution provided is to:

Modify ddms.bat in C:\android-sdk-windows\tools folder. The last line from

call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir= -jar %jarpath% %*

to:

call %java_exe% %java_debug% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs% -Dcom.android.ddms.bindir= -jar %jarpath% ping emulator 0012

Comment: Hi, The problem is solved. But the file ddms.bat was not on the format above. I anyway added 'ping emulator 5554' before the last %* on the last line. Then the error message disappeared. I also changed the version of Eclipse I used from Eclipse Classic to JAVA Developers. I also needed to push the Menu button of the emulator to be able to view the applikation screen.